# Training on biased dataset, when the bias is quantitively known

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, bias

I have a machine learning model (A neural network here) which minimizes MSE loss. The model should fallow an unbiased distribution. Nevertheless, the training set is biased, but fortunately by a known factor $w$.

Let's assume my dataset as $$X = {x_1, x_2, x_3 ... x_N}$$
where $N$ is a number of points in the dataset. Also I have a corresponding set of factors:
$$W = {w_1, w_2, w_3 ... w_N}$$
where the index corresponds to the same point/example in the dataset. The weights are normalized between 0 .. 1 and they sum to 1.
Basically every $w_i = P_{unbiased, i}/P_{biased, i} $ is a fraction of probability of drawing sample $i$ from unbiased distribution with respect to biased. So $w_i = 0.01$ means that it's 0.01 less populated in the unbiased dataset than the current one.

How I should unbias my training, so that the model will fallow unbiased distribution of my data ? Is this the same kind of problem as training on the unbalanced dataset ?

If second is true, two things come to my mind, but I don't know if they're right.

- Replicate data according to the weight - but this wilk take additional resources to train
- For every example, bias loss function according to $w_i$

Comment: What do these weights mean and how might they be related to "bias"?  Indeed, what exactly do you mean by "follow an unbiased distribution"?

Comment: Good question @whuber, the is $w = P_biased/P_unbiased$. I'll add to the question

Comment: Are you trying to tell us you are working with a *probability sample*?  It would help to know whether the values of the $w_i$ are determined by a sample design or are somehow imposed on you by, say, difficulties in data collection or other factors.  And whether any of this matters depends on your model and what it aims to do, so information about those things would be useful, too.

Comment: @whuber
> would help to know whether the values of the wi are determined by a sample design or are somehow imposed on you by, say, difficulties in data collection or other factors. 
Are imposed on me by difficulties in data collection. In general my samples have some multinomial distribution $P_0$ which I know. But the data alone are not fallowing this distribution, but they are fallowing distribution $P_b$.
Where $P_b$ is far different than $P_0$